# Fetch returning 200 and 401

Tags: javascript, fetch

I've been trying to request data from outlook.office.com and keep getting error 401. Every time it's saying No Acces-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested ressource. I'm using fetch('https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages, {headers: {'Allow-Control-Access-Origin' : '*'}}) ; which gives me a code 200 (which is a good start), and then returns an error 401. Any ideas on how to solve this and check amount of emails?

Comment: Are you testing this via localhost?

Comment: No, and I don't have access to the server as a lot of people say is configured wrong. I'm running this on a website

Comment: Then you probably don't have your domain registered in their system...hence why your origin is not being allowed

Comment: Maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial will help?

Comment: @NickDelaney where do I register it?

Comment: I am guessing here...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial#register-the-app